# Conditional insert sql server for more than one row

Tags: sql-server, insert, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I am trying to insert a value for every Call Record with a specific date, note and action when a client matches listed emails.

The problem is that there are many other call records for these clients, so if I use a select query in the Insert statement, it will add many more rows that I want - I just want 1 row per client.

Any ideas?

```
INSERT 
INTO  
    CallRecord(date, Notes, Action)
VALUES
    ( '27-DECEMBER-2017', 'Specific Note', 'Specific Action')
WHERE email 
IN ('x@gmail.com', 'y@gmail.com')
```

---

As you can see from the example data, if I would insert a row

Example data is:
**CALLRECORD TABLE**

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="52" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    ID
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="95" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    CandidateID
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="116" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    Date
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="272" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    Notes
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="76" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    Action
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="52" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    11715
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="95" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    19
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="116" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    02/01/2018
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="272" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    stuff
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="76" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    different actions
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="52" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    11751
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="95" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    19
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="116" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    09/01/2018
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="272" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    stuff
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="76" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    different actions
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="52" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    23634
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="95" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    19
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="116" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    23/01/2018
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="272" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    stuff
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="76" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    different actions
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="52" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    9180
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="95" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    21
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="116" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    27/10/2016
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="272" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    stuff
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="76" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    different actions
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="52" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    9237
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="95" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    21
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="116" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    14/11/2016
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="272" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    stuff
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="76" nowrap="" valign="top">
                <p>
                    different actions
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The candidateID relates to the Candidate table which stores the email address (with other info).

Therefore the query I was using is below. **But**, as there are multiple entries in the callrecord table for each candidate, it would insert 5 rows (3 & 2) for each entry. How can I ensure just to insert 2 records for the 2 candidates?

```
insert into  CallRecord  (date, Notes, Action)
select  '27-DECEMBER-2017','Wanted to stay as active candidate following our review', ''
from callrecord
where CandidateID in 
(
    select distinct(id)
    from Candidate
    where email  in 
    (
    'x@gmail.com', 
    'y@gmail.com')
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. As posted this is not very clear at all. Here is a great place to get started though. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Could you provide a working example or some test data that can be used to demonstrate the actual problem you have?

Comment: I updated my post to include a working example

Answer (score 0):

Use ROW_NUMBER over PARTITION BY

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ClientId ORDER BY ClientId),
        *
        FROM SourceTable
)
INSERT INTO DestinationTable
(
    ClientId,
    Col1,
    Col2
)
SELECT
    ClientId,
    Col1,
    COl2
    FROM CTE
        WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Dont I need to PARTITION on 2 fields, ClientId and Date?

Comment: If you need DIstinct Based on BOth Client ID and Date, then Yes

Comment: Do you mind giving an example of this relating to my scenario, as I am inserting specific values?